# Javascript toLocalDateString outputs different format on windows vs mac

Tags: javascript, date, locale

I'm using Javascript's `toLocalDateString` method to get the `date` of the user on their `local system time`.
However the output format of the function is different across windows and mac (using **chrome browsers on both**):

**On Windows**

[image]

**On Mac**

[image]

As you can see on windows we get format **m-dd-yyyy** whereas on mac it's **dd-mm-yyyy**. This is causing issues in my code as I need to display it in a common format using `substr` on the resulting output and fetching year, date and month separately.

Is there any way to force this to output in one particular format only or is there any other reliable way to get system's local date (I only need date not the time)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You will have to pass locals argument as below:

// US English uses month-day-year order

```
console.log(date.toLocaleDateString('en-US'))
```

// British English uses day-month-year order

```
console.log(date.toLocaleDateString('en-GB'))
```

Check reference link -
[toLocaleDateString](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/toLocaleDateString)

Answer (score 3):

There is no guarantee whatsoever how the output of `toLocaleDateString()` will look on a particular browser on a particular system. So if you need a specific format, you must either create it yourself or use some library.

If you just need separate year, day and month of the current date, why not just use the respective methods on the `Date()` object?

```
const today = new Date();
const year = today.getFullYear();
const month = today.getMonth() +1; //month count is 0-based
const day = today.getDate();
```

Comment: Yeah your solution is what my next approach would be if this doesn't work. But I wanted to understand why this doesn't work even on the same browser

Comment: Because the only specification on `toLocaleString` is, that it should somehow assemble the locale time and/or date format, without any more details. There might be browsers that try to fetch more details from the os, others don't. There might be minor differences in what information is delivered by the os, different machines may have different formats even for the same language, ...

Comment: To know, why this gives different results on windows and Mac, you'd probably have to look into the source code and/or ask the engineers at google, why they implemented it like they did.

Answer (score 0):

```
 var date= new Date();
    var formatDate;
    if(navigator.appVersion.indexOf("Win") != -1){
      formatDate= date.toLocaleDateString('en-GB');
    }
    else{
     formatDate= date.toLocaleDateString();
    }
   console.log(formatDate);
```